# Android webview doesn't display openlayers 3 map

Tags: android, android-webview, openlayers-3

I'm trying to display an openlayers 3 map in an Android webview. Only the zoom controls are displayed, the map itself not. Javascript is enabled for the webview, right to access the internet is granted. I tested on a Nexus 5 with Android 7 (API 24).

If I load exactly the same js code in Chrome on Android, the map is displayed fine. Any ideas?

**[Update]** I switched now to leaflet where the map is displayed without problems. Additionally leaflet seems to me much easier to use.

Comment: Which device, version of OS and webview are you testing on?

Comment: @Morrison: I added the information in the description.