# Trouble loading local openlayers website with browsercomponent codenameone on android

Tags: android, openlayers, codenameone

i working on a codenameone app with openlayers with a local   website (html file). The app is working good in the simulator and the webisite is running oke when loaded on the desktop webbrowser (chrome or edge) On the android device (android 5.0) the map is not loaded in the webbrowser component.
what did i do:
a. i checked the files are in place and the relative path to javascript files is working oke.
b. i made a simple openlayers webpage. But with this is the same no loading map.

```
<html>
<head>
   <meta charset="utf8" />
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ol@v7.3.0/dist/ol.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ol@v7.3.0/ol.css">
</head>
<body style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">
   <div id="map" class="map"></div>

   <script type="text/javascript">
   var view = new ol.View(
   {
      center: [0, 0],
      zoom: 2
   });

   var map = new ol.Map(
   {
      layers: [
         new ol.layer.Tile(
         {
            source: new ol.source.OSM()
         })
      ],
      target: 'map',

      view: view,
      pixelRatio: 1
   });

   var mapDiv = document.getElementById("map");
   map.setSize([mapDiv.offsetWidth/2, mapDiv.offsetHeight/2]);
   </script>
</body>
</html>
```

How can i solve this?

**Update**
On my android phone android v9.0:
a Openlayers is working on my android phone (v9.0) with the simple map.
b Openlayers is not working when i copy my big website to the homepath. i copy the files with a zip file. i have a check in the app to check if all the files are copied.Something is going wrong with loading of the javascript files of the weppage.
c My big website is working with google cloud storage.
but the javascript is loading very slow.

The app would be faster if i can store the webpagefiles local.

Comment: Possibly OpenLayers needs a more recently browser (Chrome on Android 5 is limited to version 95 I think).  OpenLayers 7 may need polyfills.  You could also try an earlier version of OpenLayers (with polyfills 6.14.1 could be made run on Internet Explorer, or even go right back to 5.3.0)

Comment: @mike openlayers 3 is working good on Android 5 in chrome but not in the native webviewer (codenameone)

Comment: This seems to be a general Android problem as discussed in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42254046/android-webview-doesnt-display-openlayers-3-map

Answer (score 0):

Can you host the html file loading openlayers in a domain, then in Codename One's BrowserComponent use

```
bc.setUrl("https://yoururl.html");
```

See this
[Loading url in BrowserComponent](https://github.com/Eric-Chomba/FeaturesCN1-Ant/blob/master/src/com/zomuhtech/cn/features/advft/Web.java)

And in 'Web' menu of this app
[FeaturesCN](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.zomuhtech.cn.features)

There could be a restriction when trying to load the following directly/locally in the BrowserComponent

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ol@v7.3.0/dist/ol.js"></script>
```

Eg. When the following Stripe JS is added directly/locally to the BrowserComponent, it loads fine on Simulator but fails on device since they check origin of the request

```
<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
```